# ls and ls -la not displaying a file that I am trying to compile (Java)

Tags: java, terminal, ls

[ls and ls -la commands are not displaying files that I want to compile. Why are my files not showing up?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgqND.png)

Comment: Because they are in another directory?

Comment: There is a file in the location Desktop/hello that I want to compile, but the file is not showing up. My only theory is that some other program may be moving the file but the file is clearly there.

Comment: Can't you copy-paste the terminal output instead of liking us to that image?

Comment: The typical UNIX command `ls` won't show files that aren't in the current directly without `-R` option. Yes, the reason is that they are not where the command scanned for files.

Answer (score 1):

> Why are my files not showing up?

Because they are not in the current directory!  They are in a different directory.  Based on this comment ...

> There is a file in the location Desktop/hello that I want to compile, but the file is not showing up.

... I am guessing that the file will show up if you run `ls -l Desktop` when you are in your home directory.  Or if you happen to be in another directory then `ls -l ~/Desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

ls and ls -a will display contents of the current directory in which you are. Does pwd command show the directory Desktop u der which you are expecting the files to be? If not you will have to CD to that directory first and then run ls command.